# There is no text for object 'ATM_BRANCH'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I created view with name 'ATM_BRANCH' but there was some error in sql statement so view did not created. But now after correcting error, I tried again but it gives me error 'There is already an object named 'ATM_BRANCH' in the database'. Then I see the views in Object explorer and there is no view with this name. I need to create the view with same name. What to do?

Comment: Perhaps it is a table rather than a view.

Comment: `but there was some error in sql statement` ... what was the error when you tried creating that view?  Was it the same "already an object" error, or was it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the view is actually still there, in some form.  First run this to confirm:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'ATM_BRANCH' AND type = 'v');
```

If that returns true, then drop the view:

```
DROP VIEW ATM_BRANCH;
```

Based on your comment, and Gordon's correct guess, `ATM_BRANCH` is actually a table.  So, if you want to name a view `ATM_BRANCH`, you'll have to drop the table first:

```
DROP TABLE ATM_BRANCH;
```

Comment: I run first query, but no record comes. I run second query , it gives error 'Cannot use DROP VIEW with 'ATM_BRANCH' because 'ATM_BRANCH' is a table. Use DROP TABLE'

Comment: If you don't want that table, then drop it and create a view by the same name.  If you _do_ really want that table, then use a different name for the view.